# Why can't I create the FormView in Silex?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, silex

I'm trying to make add fields to a form in a loop.

```
<?php
namespace resources\model;


use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;


/**
 * Class BuildTheForm
 * @package resources\model
 */
class BuildTheForm
{


/**
 * @param Application $app
 * @param array $questions
 * @return mixed
 */
public function buildTheForm(Application $app, array $questions)
{

    $answers = [];

    $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form');

    $choices = array(
        'A' => 'A Trifft auf nicht mich zu',
        'B' => 'B',
        'C' => 'C',
        'D' => 'D',
        'E' => 'E - Trifft auf mich zu'
    );

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 28; $i++) {
        array_push($answers, $i);
    }

    foreach ($answers as $answer) {
        $form->add(
            $answer,
            'choice',
            array(
                'choices' => $choices,
                'multiple' => false
            )
        );
    }

    $form->add(
        'auswerten',
        SubmitType::class
    )
    ->getForm();


    return $app['twig']->render(
        'questions.html.twig',
        array(
            'questions' => $questions,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        )
    );
}
```

The error I get is:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder::createView() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/Psychoform/resources/model/BuildTheForm.php on line 67

Do you have an idea where the Error comes from?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have anything to the loop.

It's just `FormBuilder` doesn't have method `createView` as the message says.

What you probably want to have is:

```
        'form' => $form->getForm()->createView()
```

You have to get form class from the form builder in first place. Then you can get form's view object.

Edit:

As KhorneHoly pointed out, you're calling `getForm()` earlier in:

```
$form->add(
    'auswerten',
    SubmitType::class
)
->getForm();
```

But this method doesn't modify `$form`  variable itself but it **returns** new object. Therefore you're calling it but not assigning returned form class object to anything.

You can remove `getForm()` call form here or assign it's result to a variable and call `createView()` later **on this new object**.

Comment: That was the Error:`'form' => $form->getForm()->createView()` instead of `'form' => $form->createView()` . I dont understand the Error, because i thought i already use the `->getForm()` before....... Thank u so much for helping

Comment: @freemindghost do you understand the issue now or do you need further guidance?

Comment: it would be enought to get a link to a documentation or something like that.I ask myself where do u know it from

Comment: There's nothing to document in this case. `FormBuilder::getForm()` returns `Form`, isn't that obvious?

Comment: Ok, i've got it now, thank u very much for help und explain

Comment: Great. I'm glad to help you.